# Hosting Messed Up My Fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, hosting

I am working on a practice page to practice some new techniques I'm learning. I got it to look pretty cool but when I finally got hosting to work on Google Drive, it messed up a lot of my custom fonts linked in from Google Fonts. Am I going to have to add browser compatibility tags? If so where should I put them? I'm using Firefox by the way.

This is my file before hosting with all the fonts I want. It's uploaded on Dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/log09xpyvl14njm/collapsing%20header%20page.html

This is a link to the hosted version with the messed up fonts on Google Drive:

https://30ae84b57730686f022407a9f81608f17e555736.googledrive.com/host/0B817Egz64pkKMjc4TENZVnVIR0U/collapsing%20header%20page.html

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting your Google hosted fonts from "http" to "https".

Answer (score 0):

you have a missing stylesheet (style.css), add it and it should work fine, there's no way Google fonts are messed up by the hosting

Comment: The css is included in the style tag. It doesn't need the stylesheet. I forgot to delete the css link when I moved it all into the style tags. Thanks though.